# how to retrive data from a data by using current date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to list all the  data from a table by using current date, it should pull all the records on particular date 
like 4-october 2015
it should pull 4- jan to 4-dec irrespective of year

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE date >=CURRENT_DATE()
```

please help me

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Give some sample data and your expected results

Comment: Its very clear that I just want to pull up the records on particular date, suppose if date is 19-09-2015, I need to pull the records of 19th day of every month from jan to dec irrespective of year

Answer (score 0):

your **date** column must be type **date** (2015-09-19) or timestamp

for specific day:

```
$day = '2014-09-04';
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE date = CURDATE($day);
```

for data ranges:

```
$from = '2015-01-01';
$to = '2015-04-01';
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE date >= CURDATE($from) AND date < CURDATE($to);
```